# Adding Objects to another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, react-context

I'm trying to add object inside an object with id as a key in react provider. Following is the use case.

```js
const [memberList, setMemberList] = useState({
  homeTeam: [],
  awayTeam: [],
  homeTeamClone: {},
});
```

I can successfully add member to an array, however I'm more keen to add that in `homeTeamClone` object.

example of object = {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704","memberName":"Adam"}

I want final result as

```js
homeTeamClone: {
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704","memberName":"Adam"},
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5705": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5705","memberName":"Chris"},
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5706": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5706","memberName":"Martin"},
}
```

I tried `Object.assign(homeTeamClone, member)` but did not get the expected result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And the problem is? `homeTeamClone[member.id] = member` (+ some cloning of `member` if necessary)

Comment: you can try this for cloning an object `const newObject = { ...baseObject }`... and to clone an array would be `const newArray = Array.from(baseArray)`... always you can check the `cloneDeep` method from lodah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is how to set individual member than you can do this:

```js
const member = { id: '3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704', memberName: 'Adam' };

setMemberList({
  ...memberList,
  homeTeamClone: {
    ...memberList.homeTeamClone,
    [member.id]: member,
  },
});
```

In this case spread all old values and add new one. (In case user with same ID is added again, object value will be from the new one)

Comment: @VANKD np. Glad I could help